# Intellisense accept shortcut

Tags: sql, intellisense, ssms, sql-server-2008

is it possible to change sql intellisense accept suggestion key? I'm used to use enter, but sql management studio seem to accept only Tab or Space key - enter just cancels suggestion and makes new line. I've searched options but there is not much for intellisense.

Thanks

Comment: What version are you on? Enter works for me. In fact everything seems to "work" for me. I have constant battles trying to type something like `Select(CAST '' AS XML)` and 
not having it converted to `Select(CAST '' ASCII XML_SCHEMA_NAMESPACE)`

Comment: I'm working with MS SQL Server Management Studio 10.50.1600.1 (R2)

Comment: Ah I'm not on R2 - I would much prefer the behaviour you are getting!

Comment: I'm also searching for a way to turn off accepting by space - It is hard to write even simple "Select ID from Table' - it is converted to Select IDENTITY....

Comment: I've gotten into the habit of replacing <SPACE> with <ESC><SPACE> when I'm typing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not. SSMS is sometimes limited in customizing of shortcut keys. There are some third party plugins that can affect its behavior though, so that may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of 
[SSMS 2012 Intellisense Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555138/ssms-2012-intellisense-behavior)

Short version - to toggle behavior each and every time you open a tab  press [CTRL][ALT][SPACE]

SSMSBoost looks like it had the feature but lost it, they are trying to put it back but at this time the preference page that changed that behavior was lost.
http://www.ssmsboost.com/social/yaf_postst5301_Intellisense-Default-Completion-Behavior.aspx#post11860

Comment: Feature is restored in SSMSBoost 2.16