# SSMS 2012 Intellisense Behavior

Tags: sql-server, intellisense, ssms

It seems like the behavior of intellisense has been changed in SSMS 2012 so that it does not behave the same as Visual Studio or SSMS 2008.

Previously I would always hit SPACE, and that would insert the current highlighted word from intellisense. But in SSMS 2012 I have to hit TAB or hit DOWN ARROW then SPACE

Here is what SSMS 2012 looks like as I'm typing a query

[image: SSMS2012 Intellisense]

If I hit space then this happens:

[image]

In SSMS 2008 it looks differently

[image]

And in visual studio

[image]

In both of those simply hitting SPACE will insert the word. Is there a way to customize or change the intellisense behavior in SSMS 2012?

Comment: Perhaps duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718657/intellisense-window-has-input-field-and-doesnt-commit-on-space

Comment: I'm glad i'm not the only one not happy with this new behavior, LOL.  I had to double check with VS2010's intellisense to see if it was my imagination and, nope, it's definately different.  What's even more fustrating is when i fully type the table/column/whatever and hit enter (new line), but what enter is doing is accepting the value from intellisense, so i have to hit enter TWICE.  garh!  I LOVE intellisense, and wish there was a way to put it back to the way it was :(

Comment: I just learned about AutoHotkey. I imagine you can write a small piece of script, that let's create you a keyboard combination that gives back double enters. Or possibly some other combination that suits your needs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pressing CTRL + ALT + SPACE toggles the intellisense behavior, so that space will commit the entry.

Thanks to xQbert who found [this existing question for visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718657/intellisense-window-has-input-field-and-doesnt-commit-on-space) that answers it

Comment: at least it helped me reduce my blood pressure

Answer (score 13):

The problem is a bit more serious in my opinion.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> will change the behavior but only for the current tab. If you open a new tab, it goes back to the new "default" behavior. So the real big issue is that there is no way to save the behavior I want as the default behavior. We'll have to keep hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> every single time!!!

Comment: Yes i have the freaking same problem how can we fix ?

Comment: Someone started a report with microsoft.  Click this link, use your MS login and vote up the issue.  
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/955683/how-to-make-sql-server-2014-remember-ctrl-alt-space-behaviour-at-new-tabs-remember-permanently

Comment: Microsoft fixed the issue so you don't have to repeat the procedure for every new tab. :)